# How to refer css file from visual webpart

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SharePoint 2010.
I have added SharePoint Mapped Folder mapped to below path 
{SharePointRoot}\Template\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES
Inside this I have added new folder with the name of project and css file.
I am trying to refer this css file using below

```
<SharePoint:CssLink ID="cssLink1" runat="server" DefaultUrl="~/Template/LAYOUTS/1033/STYLES/VisualWebPartProject/Stylesheet1.css" />

<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" name~/Template/LAYOUTS/1033/STYLES/VisualWebPartProject/Stylesheet1.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Template/LAYOUTS/1033/STYLES/VisualWebPartProject/Stylesheet1.css"/>
```

Webpart showing below error for CSSLink and CSSRegistration 
Error Rendering Control - CssRegistration1An error occurred while fetching preview

In all three case css is not getting applied to the webpart but when I add css code on ascx page then it is getting applied to the webpart.

Can you please suugest me what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

The path which you provided for css which is located in layouts folder on the server is incorrect. You should use path prefixed with `/_layouts` instead of `~/Template/LAYOUTS`. `/_layouts` is virtual directory in IIS SharePoint web site which is mapped to `Template/LAYOUTS` folder on the server.

Try this:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="/_layouts/1033/STYLES/VisualWebPartProject/Stylesheet1.css" ID="CustomCss" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried above code but it didn't work. also in design mode of visual studio, it is showing Webpart showing error "Error Rendering Control - CustomCss An error occurred while fetching preview"
Thanks for taking time to help me out.

Comment: Maybe this css is not present on server? Have you tried using same path with link tag?

Comment: Yes, tried the same with link tag too but no suucess.